# Aggregation functions do not work properly in Oracle 10g

Tags: sql, join, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

I use the **Oracle 10g** version

```
select * from v$version
```

Result:

```
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.5.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.5.0  Production
TNS for Linux: Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.5.0 - Production
```

There is query **#1**. This query works correctly and produces the expected result.

```
SELECT   ai.file_id,
         fi.tr_file,
         bi.recv_file
FROM (SELECT fe.file_id FROM file_journal fe WHERE fe.out_ = 0) ai,
         (SELECT DISTINCT recv_file FROM send_docs sd WHERE sd.recv_file IS NOT NULL) bi,
         (SELECT DISTINCT f1.file_id tr_file
                FROM send_treasure s,
                         payment_docs  p1,
                         payment_docs  p2,
                         file_journal  f1,
                         file_journal  f3,
                         file_journal  f4,
                         r_file_states t1,
                         r_file_states t2
             WHERE s.sid = p1.sid
                 AND p1.recv_file = f1.file_id
                 AND s.send_file = p2.recv_file
                 AND p2.recv_file = f3.file_id
                 AND f3.state = t1.code
                 AND f4.state = t2.code
                 AND p2.send_file_b = f4.file_id) fi
WHERE ai.file_id = bi.recv_file
 AND ai.file_id = fi.tr_file
```

*This query is simplified, left the columns that are needed to join*.

This query returns the following expected result:

```
    file_id     tr_file     recv_file
-------------------------------------- 
1   1623156799  1623156799  1623156799
2   1623156812  1623156812  1623156812
3   1623156813  1623156813  1623156813
4   1623156814  1623156814  1623156814
5   1623156815  1623156815  1623156815
6   1623156816  1623156816  1623156816
7   ....
and so on, a total of 18 entries.
```

Then, I need to **count the number of records**. To do this, I do the following query **#2**.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
FROM (SELECT ai.file_id,
             fi.tr_file,
             bi.recv_file
            FROM (SELECT fe.file_id FROM file_journal fe WHERE fe.out_ = 0) ai,
                 (SELECT DISTINCT recv_file FROM send_docs sd WHERE sd.recv_file IS NOT NULL) bi,
                 (SELECT DISTINCT f1.file_id tr_file
                                FROM send_treasure s,
                                     payment_docs  p1,
                                     payment_docs  p2,
                                     file_journal  f1,
                                     file_journal  f3,
                                     file_journal  f4,
                                     r_file_states t1,
                                     r_file_states t2
                             WHERE s.sid = p1.sid
                                 AND p1.recv_file = f1.file_id
                                 AND s.send_file = p2.recv_file
                                 AND p2.recv_file = f3.file_id
                                 AND f3.state = t1.code
                                 AND f4.state = t2.code
                                 AND p2.send_file_b = f4.file_id) fi
             WHERE ai.file_id = bi.recv_file
                 AND ai.file_id = fi.tr_file)
```

This query returns the following expected result:

```
CNT
---
18
```

Then I make another query **#3**. **And this query is not working as it should**.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt
                FROM (SELECT ai.file_id,
                             fi.tr_file,
                             bi.recv_file
                            FROM (SELECT fe.file_id FROM file_journal fe WHERE fe.out_ = 0) ai,
                                 (SELECT DISTINCT recv_file FROM send_docs sd WHERE sd.recv_file IS NOT NULL) bi,
                                 (SELECT DISTINCT f1.file_id tr_file
                                                FROM send_treasure s,
                                                     payment_docs  p1,
                                                     payment_docs  p2,
                                                     file_journal  f1,
                                                     file_journal  f3,
                                                     file_journal  f4,
                                                     r_file_states t1,
                                                     r_file_states t2
                                             WHERE s.sid = p1.sid
                                                 AND p1.recv_file = f1.file_id
                                                 AND s.send_file = p2.recv_file
                                                 AND p2.recv_file = f3.file_id
                                                 AND f3.state = t1.code
                                                 AND f4.state = t2.code
                                                 AND p2.send_file_b = f4.file_id) fi
                             WHERE ai.file_id = bi.recv_file
                                 AND ai.file_id = fi.tr_file))
```

This query returns a result:

```
CNT
---
0
```

As you can see, the result is **incorrect**.

**The correct result should be:**

```
CNT
---
18
```

P.S.
Create a *view* with name `v_count_test`. Then make query to it, we get the following:

```
create or replace view v_count_test as
here query #2

select * from V_COUNT_TEST t
```

This query returns a result:

```
CNT
---
0
```

I would be very grateful for the help and clarification of the situation.

Thank you so much!

---

Demonstration video incorrect running queries.

[image: Demonstration video incorrect running queries.]

Comment: That looks like a bug.

Comment: Agreed ..This is a bug. Nevertheless, what about trying using a alias to your query.

Comment: Using the alias does not change the behavior. The result remains the same.

Comment: You may wish to create minimal reproducable sample to confirm the bug.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not create a reproducible example, because in the query participates 4 different table. If you modify the query or delete the table from the query, the query **starts to work properly**.  For example, if you delete a **distinct** in the query `fi`, the query works correctly.